# unnest row into multiple json objects

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql

Currently I have a table `my_table` with columns (id,product_id,text) and transform data into a json object like so:

```
SELECT
  json_agg(
    json_build_object(
      'id', t.id,
      'parent_id', t.product_id,
      'text', t.text
    )
  )
FROM my_table AS t
```

Now that I am adding more columns to `my_table`, I need to return a JSON object per each row from the selected list of rows from this table.
Basically, talbe columns will be (id,product_id,text1,text2,text3)

And I want to return 3 identical objects with 1 different value of text (for text1,text2,text3)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest()` to yield a single row as three ones:

```
select id, product_id, unnest(array[text1, text2, text3]) as text
from my_table
```

Create the json array from the above query:

```
select
    json_agg (
        json_build_object(
            'id', id,
            'product_id', product_id,
            'text', text
        )
    )
from (
    select id, product_id, unnest(array[text1, text2, text3]) as text
    from my_table
    ) t
```

or

```
select
    json_agg (
        json_build_object(
            'id', id,
            'product_id', product_id,
            'text', text
        )
    )
from my_table
cross join unnest(array[text1, text2, text3]) as text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to use `unnest` in my `FROM (...)` but I did not realize how it worked in fact.

Comment: Using the function in the `from` clause with lateral join perhaps is more elegant, see the updated answer.

Comment: To me, the initial answer reads easier. Are there any reasons one should prefer the latter?

Comment: They are roughly equivalent in this case. Anyway, I would recommend taming with the second variant as it may be very helpful in more complex queries.

Comment: I see. I'll try to!

Comment: It seems there is no way to define a constraint which operates on rows unnested in the way used in the answer. But I'm not sure I understand well what you are asking. Maybe ask a new question with sample table structure and/or sample data.

Comment: How can I make this `unnest(array_remove(array[LOWER(text1), LOWER(text2), LOWER(text3)], NULL))` return only unique values based on LOWERed versions and removed NULLs?